# similar word concatination (merge)

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I have many records where 2 columns contain words which shall be uniquely concatenated. all words shall be distinct in the result.
The order of both text arrays shall be kept.

> **Col1**: mr. spock *eats 13 fish*
>
> **Col2**: **he** *eats 13 fish*

The idea is to concatenate only missing words.

> result: mr. spock **he** *eats 13 fish*

I've tried to create arrays of both text columns with PostgreSQL's function

`regexp_split_to_array`

This is, what solved my problem:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION merge_strings(str1 text[], str2 text[])
  RETURNS text[]
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$body$
DECLARE
    res TEXT[];
    t1 TEXT;
    t2 TEXT;
    pos2 int := 1;
    pos3 int;
begin
    FOREACH t1 in array str1 LOOP
        pos3 := array_position(str2, t1, pos2);
        while (pos2 <= pos3) LOOP
        --iterate over words in second text-array until first found word from first text-array 
            t2 := str2[pos2];
            if (t2 != t1) then
                --only use words that are not equal         
                res := array_append(res, t2);
            end if;
            pos2 := pos2 + 1;
        END LOOP;
        res := array_append(res, t1);
    END LOOP;
    FOREACH t2 in array str2 LOOP
    --add all missing words from second text-array
        pos3 := array_position(res, t2);
        if (pos3 is null) then
            res := array_append(res, t2);
        end if;
    end loop;
    return res;
END;
$body$
```

Comment: now I trying to solve this with ts_vector...

Comment: This seems very hard or underspecified. How would the system know that is has to concatenate in the way you describe instead of for example "he mr.spock ..."?

Comment: This seems very clear to me, not sure why it's getting downvoted. This is essentially a *backtracking* problem. Is the "missing text" always left-anchored?

Comment: Also, are you trying to highlight the difference? what's the end goal?

Comment: For now I've found a solution. Thank You @EvanCarroll for pointing out to use a function:

Comment: If the question is reopened, please take the solution out of the question, and post it as your answer to your own question.

Answer (score 1):

From your question it's unclear whether you only want to search for common text only at the end of strings, or anywhere in the strings. Nonetheless, at the core this seems to build on the [Longest Common Substring Problem (wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem) in computer science.

I don't know of a readily-available function in PostgreSQL to find longest common substrings; so I suspect that the best solution will be to implement what you need in a procedural language similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30315934/sql-find-longest-common-string-between-rows.

Doing it purely in (set-based) SQL will be rather complicated - ending up something like https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/finding-the-longest-common-starting-substring-using-sql. That particular solution only searches on substrings at the beginning of the field but could probably be modified to do what you want. The idea of using ts_vector to solve this more efficiently in SQL is interesting too - I hope you report back if you find anything useful!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this...

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (str)
        substring( substr FROM 1 FOR l ) AS difference,
        overlay( str PLACING FORMAT('--> %s<--', substring(substr FROM 1 FOR l)) FROM (length(str) - length(substr) +l + 1) FOR 0) AS overlaid
FROM (
        SELECT str, substr, l, position( substring(substr FROM l) in str ) AS p
        FROM ( VALUES (
                'mr. spock eats 13 fish',
                'he eats 13 fish'
        )) AS t(str, substr)
        CROSS JOIN LATERAL generate_series(1,length(substr)) AS l
)
AS t
WHERE t.p = 0
ORDER BY str, l DESC;

 difference |            overlaid             
------------+---------------------------------
 he         | mr. spock--> he<-- eats 13 fish
(1 row)
```

I think this could be maid faster if you reversed both inputs and didn't use `position()`

Also worth pointing out that it's probably a gazillion times faster to do this in `plperl` than with SQL.